# How to call external service (Non MSA) from Api gateway (Zuul) in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

In my Spring boot micro service application,I am using Zuul proxy as edge service in my API Gateway. I need to call external service which is not registered in eureka server(Non Micro Service Architecture). How Can I call that external service from my api gateway. (Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `application.properties` file you configure as below:

```
zuul.routes.external.path /external/**
zuul.routes.external.url http://urltoexternalservice.com/external
```

Comment: Thanks @mohamed . Its working fine . I have tried this.